# Why is the complexity O(log(n^2)*(log(n))

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The complexity of this code is O(log(n^2)*log(n), and i don't understand how we arrive to this result.

According to me, the nested while's big O should be just log(n) since its a while loop and we divide j by 4 everytime we enter the loop, and same for the initial while loop with i divided by 2. I especially dont understand which while loop has the O(log^2(n)) complexity

```
c = 0
i = n * n
while i > 0:
    j = n
    while j > 0:
        c += 1
        j = j//4
    i = i//2
print c
```

Comment: `lg (n^2) == 2 lg n = O(lg n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to be coming up with `O(log_4(n)*log_2(n))` as the complexity.  First, appreciate that the outer and inner `while` loops are not correlated.  That is to say, the outer loop in `i` is independent of the inner loop in `j`.  Here are the complexities of the outer and inner loop, in terms of `n`:

- outer loop: `O(log_2(n))`.  This is because the loop starts with `n^2`, and then decrements the counter by factors of 2, which is therefore `log_2` behavior.  As @chepner has commented:

  `O(log_2(n^2)) == 2*O(log_2(n)) = O(log_2(n))`
- inner loop: `O(log_4(n))`.  This loop begins at `n`, and decrements the counter by factors of 4, which is `log_4` behavior.

Your current guess is almost right, except that you might have missed the bases of the logarithms.

Comment: The bases aren't relevant. Both are constants independent of `n` and can be ignored.

Comment: Yes; most texts will use the notation `lg n` as a sort of base-agnostic logarithm, which is not to be confused with ISO usage of `lg` as an abbreviation for base-10 logarithms.